# Why I am getting this error message: bash: find/usr/share/help: no such file or directory

Tags: bash

I am trying use the find binary to output all the files names located under `/usr/share/help` ending with`. page`. After entering `find/usr//share/help/ -name *.page` I am getting error message above. What I am doing wrong? Any suggestions, help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands and their arguments must be separated by whitespace - not

```
find/usr//share/help/
```

but

```
find /usr/share/help/
```

You should also enclose shell wildcards like `*.page` in quotes when you use them as arguments to the `find` command - otherwise the shell will try to expand them to names of files in the current directory. So

```
find /usr/share/help/ -name '*.page'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer helped me fix my mistake

Comment: @Michael260, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)